# How to create 3D extruded text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, lettering

I am pretty sure I'm not using the right terminology, but I'm trying to create the same effect in this image:

[image]

Is there any way to do this in Illustrator? What is the proper terminology for that effect? Any help would greatly be appreciated. I don't even know how to google that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called 'extruding' an object. In illustrator, select your text and apply the Extrude & Bevel effect (Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel...). Check the 'preview' box and play around with the options in the dialogue box that appears to get the desired result.

[image]

You don't have to expand your text before applying the effect. This way, you can change the text after applying.